# Simple OOP Blackjack game in Java

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, playing-cards

I've created a relatively simple Blackjack game in java. The reason why I decided to do this specific project was to improve my object orientated programming in java.

I will post my code so feel free to come with criticism etc. I am reading my first course in Java, have that in mind.

Player class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Player {

private String nickName;
private int playerNumOfCards;
ArrayList<Card> playerHand;

public Player (String name){
    this.nickName = name;
    playerHand = new ArrayList<Card>();

}

public String getNickName() {
    return nickName;
}

public void addCard(Card aCard){
    playerHand.add(aCard);
    this.playerNumOfCards++;
}

public int getHandSum(){
    int totalSum = 0;
    for(Card countSum: playerHand){
        totalSum = totalSum + countSum.getFace();
    }
    return totalSum;
}

public void getPlayerHand(boolean hideCard) {
    System.out.println(this.nickName + "s current hand.");
    for ( int c = 0; c < playerNumOfCards; c++){
        if(c == 0 && !hideCard){
            System.out.println("[Hidden card]");
        } else {
            System.out.println(playerHand.get(c).toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Card class

```
public class Card {

private Face face; //Face of card, i.e "King" & "Queen"
private Suit suit; //Suit of card, i.e "Hearts" & "diamonds"
int total = 0;

public Card (Face cardFace, Suit cardSuit){ //Constructor which initializes card's face and suit
    this.face = cardFace;
    this.suit = cardSuit;
}

public int getFace(){
     return face.getFaceValue();
}

public String getSuit(){
    return suit.PrintSuitText();
}

public String toString(){ //return String representation of Card
    return face + " of " + suit;
}
}
```

Suit enum

```
public enum Suit {

HEARTS(" Hearts"),
SPADES(" Spades"),
DIAMONDS(" Diamonds"),
CLUBS(" Clubs");

private final String suitText;

private Suit(String suitText){
    this.suitText = suitText;
}

public String PrintSuitText(){
    return suitText;
}
}
```

Face enum

```
public enum Face {

ACE(1), DEUCE (2), THREE (3),
FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6),
SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9),
TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10),
KING(10);


private final int faceValue;

private Face(int faceValue){
    this.faceValue = faceValue;
}

public int getFaceValue(){
    return faceValue;
}
}
```

DeckOfCard class

```
import java.util.Random;
public class DeckOfCards {

private Card[] deck;
private static final Random random = new Random();

private int currentCard; //index of next Card to be deal (0-51)
private static int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52; //Constant number of cards

public DeckOfCards(){

    Face [] faces = {Face.ACE, Face.DEUCE, Face.THREE, Face.FOUR, Face.FIVE, Face.SIX,
                     Face.SEVEN, Face.EIGHT, Face.NINE, Face.TEN, Face.JACK, Face.QUEEN,
                     Face.KING};
    Suit[] suits = {Suit.HEARTS, Suit.SPADES, Suit.DIAMONDS, Suit.CLUBS};

    deck = new Card [NUMBER_OF_CARDS]; // create array with Cards (52)
    currentCard = 0;

    //Populate deck with Cards
    for(int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++)
        deck [count] = new Card(faces [count % 13], suits [count / 13]);
}

public void shuffleDeck(){
    currentCard = 0;

    for (int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++){

        int second = random.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_CARDS); //Select a random card from number 0-51 (Number_of_cards)

        //Loops through all the cards and swaps it with the "Second" card which is randomly chosen card from hte same list.
        Card temp = deck[first];
        deck [first] = deck [second];
        deck [second] = temp;
    }
}

public void getCardDeck(){
    int start = 1;
    for(Card k : deck) {
        System.out.println("" + start + "/52 " + k);
        start++;
    }
}

public Card dealNextCard(){

    //Get the top card
    Card topCard = this.deck[0];

    //shift all the subsequent cards to the left by one index
    for(int currentCard = 1; currentCard < NUMBER_OF_CARDS; currentCard ++){
        this.deck[currentCard-1] = this.deck[currentCard];
    }
    this.deck[NUMBER_OF_CARDS-1] = null;

    //decrement the number of cards in our deck
    this.NUMBER_OF_CARDS--;

    return topCard;
}
}
```

Main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BlackJackGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean stay = false;

    System.out.println("What nickName would you like to have?");
    String pAnswer = scanner.nextLine();
    Player me = new Player(pAnswer);
    Player dealer = new Player("Dealer");


    System.out.println("Would you like to start a new game?  'Yes/No' :");
    pAnswer = scanner.nextLine();

    if (pAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {

        DeckOfCards deck1 = new DeckOfCards();
        Card card1 = new Card(Face.ACE, Suit.CLUBS);
        deck1.shuffleDeck();

        me.addCard(deck1.dealNextCard());
        me.addCard(deck1.dealNextCard());
        me.getPlayerHand(true);
        System.out.println(" ");
        dealer.addCard(deck1.dealNextCard());
        dealer.addCard(deck1.dealNextCard());
        dealer.getPlayerHand(false);

        //PLAYER
        do {
            System.out.println("Would " + me.getNickName() + " like to bust or stay? 'Bust/Stay'");
            pAnswer = scanner.nextLine();
            //BUST
            if (pAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Bust")) {
                me.addCard(deck1.dealNextCard());
                System.out.println(me.getHandSum());
                if (me.getHandSum() > 21) {
                    System.out.println("You busted and got a total of " + me.getHandSum() + ". Dealer wins this time! ");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            //STAY
            if (pAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("stay")) {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to stay. Your hand: " + me.getHandSum());
            }

        } while (pAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Bust"));

        //DEALER
        stay = false;

        do {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("- Dealers turn -");
            //DRAW CARD
            if (dealer.getHandSum() <= 15) {
                dealer.addCard(deck1.dealNextCard());
                if(dealer.getHandSum() == 15){
                    System.out.println("Blackjack! Dealer won.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (dealer.getHandSum() > 21) {
                    System.out.println("Dealer busted and got a total of " + dealer.getHandSum() + ". " + me.getNickName() + " wins this time!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Dealer has chosen to stay!");
                int totalDealerSum = dealer.getHandSum();
                int totalPlayerSum = me.getHandSum();

                if(totalDealerSum > totalPlayerSum){
                    System.out.println("Both players has decided to stay. The winner is " + dealer.getNickName() + " with a total of " +  totalDealerSum + ".");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Both players has decided to stay. The winner is " + me.getNickName() + " with a total of " + totalPlayerSum + ".");
                }
                stay = false;
            }

        } while (stay);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: DeckOfCards.faces and DeckOfCards.suits are a bit redundant - why not use `Face.values()` and `Suit.values()` ?

Comment: Your program actually doesn't work. Are you sure you didn't upload old code?

Comment: Your code does not follow the Tell Don't ask principle.  You should replace all of your getter with a method that does something with the value.  So instead of getX(), replace with something like displayX().  You should also familiarise yourself with these principles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Comment: @saucecode What is it that doesn't work? Is there a problem with the existing code or is there some code that's missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example run that shows that the rules of the game are not being followed.  If I started with 5♣︎ and 5♥, then receive an Ace, then I've achieved 21.  I should have won.

Also note that "bust or stay" is not the right terminology.  Nobody *wants* to bust.  It should ask whether I want to "hit or stay".

```
$ java BlackJackGame
What nickName would you like to have?
200_success
Would you like to start a new game?  'Yes/No' :
Yes
200_successs current hand.
FIVE of CLUBS
FIVE of HEARTS

Dealers current hand.
[Hidden card]
TEN of HEARTS
Would 200_success like to bust or stay? 'Bust/Stay'
Bust
11
Would 200_success like to bust or stay? 'Bust/Stay'
Stay
You have chosen to stay. Your hand: 11

- Dealers turn -
Dealer has chosen to stay!
Both players has decided to stay. The winner is Dealer with a total of 20.
```

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the quality of the code is very good. 
There is good breakdown of the code into classes and methods, good utilization of OO paradigms like data abstraction, proper use of features like enums.

Here are my comments:

### Player class

- `getPlayerHand()` the naming convention dictates that this method should have return something but it doesn't. it protins to stdout a `String` representation of the class. so perhaps the name `printPlayerHand()` is more appropriate. However, best practice convention is for a class to provide a `String` representation by overriding `toString()` method and let the caller decide what to do with that `String` (maybe print to stderr? maybe send to UI? many choices)
- `getHandSum()` it is just too pretty a name...

### Card class

- `getFace()` the name suggests that this getter method returns a `Face` instance, but it returns a property of the `Face` instance variable. so either rename to `getFaceValue()` or return the `Face` instance variable and let the caller chain method calls to get the value: `getFace().getFaceValue()`. I would go with 2nd option since it allows caller to get whatever they wish from `Face` instance variable.
- `total` seems like leftover from abandoned development...
- `getSuit()` same comment as `getPlayerHand()`

### DeckOfCard class

- in the constructor, you populate the deck and use the magic number 13. it is the length of the faces array. althouth it is unlikely that a new face will be introduced anytime in the future, still it is good for clarity to erplace the literal with a calculated number
- `shuffleDeck()` it is ok to do the shuffling for practice. However, you should know that Java has built-in feature to shuffle collections (like `List` and such)

Comment: Actually the code is very poor because of all those getters.

Answer (score 1):

## Review

### Code does not work as intended

I have no idea if you uploaded your latest code, but this one here doesn't seem to work.  Actually that's a reason to close this topic:

> Code not implemented or not working as intended: Code Review is a
> community where programmers peer-review your working code to address
> issues such as security, maintainability, performance, and
> scalability. We require that the code be working correctly, to the
> best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review.

I made this review for you anyways, but keep this in mind for future questions. I uploaded a working version of your code below.

### Java Conventions

Good Job.

### Close Scanner

Maybe you saw the waring java gave you, that your scanner is not closed at all. In this example it doesn't make a difference, but it's good practice.

### Naming

Some fields seems to have redundant names. You could rename some:

- `Player.playerNumOfCards` > `Player.numOfCards`
- `Player.playerHand` > `Player.hand`
- `Suit.suitText` > `Suit.text`

### Obsolete code

#### Defining Enum.values() yourself

There is no need for

```
Face [] faces = {Face.ACE, Face.DEUCE, Face.THREE, Face.FOUR, Face.FIVE, Face.SIX,
                 Face.SEVEN, Face.EIGHT, Face.NINE, Face.TEN, Face.JACK, Face.QUEEN,
                 Face.KING};
Suit[] suits = {Suit.HEARTS, Suit.SPADES, Suit.DIAMONDS, Suit.CLUBS};
```

Since there are `Face.values()` and `Suit.values()`, which will return exactly those arrays.

#### No need fo Suits.suitText

As I have been reworking your code, I noticed that you don't need this field at all.

### Replace DeckOfCards.deck by an ArrayList

Doing so saves you alot of trouble. See example

### Use as many private fields as possible

Actually your can make all of your `private` fields `final`. Good practice.

### You may remove the getters of final fields

Since msot of your fields are final, you may remove the getters and make the fields prublic instead. More information: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275691/is-public-final-completely-not-ok-in-constant-enum-fields

### NUMBER_OF_CARDS  is kinda weird

`NUMBER_OF_CARDS` is supposed to be a class constant, but at some point it seems like you decided to make a dirty workaround happen. I fixed this in my example.

### Don't use System.out.print inside a method

Just don't. Instead return a String, which can be printed by whoever called your method. Helpful for building long Strings: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

---

## Code example

**Card.java**

```
public class Card {

    private final Face face;

    private final Suit suit;

    public Card(Face face, Suit suit) {
        this.face = face;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Face getFace() {
        return face;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return face + " of " + suit;
    }

}
```

**Deck.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck {

    private final ArrayList<Card> cards;

    public Deck() {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        // populate deck with cards
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (Face face : Face.values()) {
                cards.add(new Card(face, suit));
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    public Card draw() {
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(i + 1);
            sb.append('/');
            sb.append(cards.size());
            sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(cards.get(i));
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**Face.java**

```
public enum Face {

    ACE(1), DEUCE(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(
            10), KING(10);

    private final int value;

    private Face(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

**Player.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Player {

    private final String nickname;

    private final ArrayList<Card> hand;

    public Player(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void addCard(Card card) {
        hand.add(card);
    }

    public int getHandSum() {
        int handSum = 0;
        for (Card card : hand) {
            handSum += card.getFace().getValue();
        }
        return handSum;
    }

    public String getHandAsString(boolean hideCard) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(nickname + "\'s current hand:");
        sb.append('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0 && hideCard) {
                sb.append("[Hidden card]");
                sb.append('\n');
            } else {
                sb.append(hand.get(i));
                sb.append('\n');
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**Suit.java**

```
public enum Suit {

    HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS;

}
```

**BlackJackGame.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJackGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nickname;
        String input;

        // ask for nickname
        System.out.println("What nickname would you like to have?");
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        nickname = input;

        // mainloop
        do {

            // new game message
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("A new game has begun.");
            System.out.println();

            // init
            Player player = new Player(nickname);
            Player dealer = new Player("Dealer");
            Deck deck = new Deck();
            deck.shuffle();
            boolean gameOver = false;

            // give cards to the player
            player.addCard(deck.draw());
            player.addCard(deck.draw());
            System.out.println(player.getHandAsString(false));

            // give cards to the dealer
            dealer.addCard(deck.draw());
            dealer.addCard(deck.draw());
            System.out.println(dealer.getHandAsString(true));

            // player's turn
            do {
                System.out.println("Would " + player.getNickname() + " like to bust or stay? 'Bust/Stay'");
                do {
                    input = scanner.nextLine();
                } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("Bust") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("Stay"));

                // BUST
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Bust")) {
                    player.addCard(deck.draw());
                    System.out.println(player.getNickname() + " drew a card.");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(player.getHandAsString(false));
                    if (player.getHandSum() > 21) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "You busted and got a total of " + player.getHandSum() + ". Dealer wins this time!");
                        gameOver = true;
                    }
                }
                // STAY
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("stay")) {
                    System.out.println("You have chosen to stay. Your hand: " + player.getHandSum());
                }

            } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Bust") && !gameOver);

            // dealer's turn
            if (!gameOver) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("- Dealers turn -");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(dealer.getHandAsString(false));
            }

            while (!gameOver) {

                if (dealer.getHandSum() <= 15) {
                    // DRAW CARD
                    dealer.addCard(deck.draw());
                    System.out.println(dealer.getNickname() + " drew another card");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(dealer.getHandAsString(false));
                    if (dealer.getHandSum() == 15) {
                        System.out.println("Blackjack! Dealer won.");
                        gameOver = true;
                    }
                    if (dealer.getHandSum() > 21) {
                        System.out.println("Dealer busted and got a total of " + dealer.getHandSum() + ". "
                                + player.getNickname() + " wins this time!");
                        gameOver = true;
                    }

                } else {
                    // STAY
                    System.out.println("Dealer has chosen to stay!");
                    System.out.println();
                    int totalDealerSum = dealer.getHandSum();
                    int totalPlayerSum = player.getHandSum();

                    if (totalDealerSum > totalPlayerSum) {
                        System.out.println("Both players has decided to stay. The winner is " + dealer.getNickname()
                                + " with a total of " + totalDealerSum + ".");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Both players has decided to stay. The winner is " + player.getNickname()
                                + " with a total of " + totalPlayerSum + ".");
                    }
                    gameOver = true;
                }

            }

            // ask for new game
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to start a new game?  'Yes/No' :");
            do {
                input = scanner.nextLine();
            } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));

        } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

        // tidy up
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: If the code is obviously not working correctly, please don't answer the question. Flag it for closure instead.

Answer (score 0):

One more point on OOP:

You hold your deck in an *array*. Because of this you need to "move" the cards in the deck after getting the top most.

You may better use a `Collection` type  to hold them. Since order is important you man use an implementation of `List`. Then the whole method `dealNextCard()` would reduce to:

```
private final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();

public Card dealNextCard(){
    return this.deck.remove(0);
}
```

This also would remove the need to track the number of cards left since you can call `isEmpty()` on  any `Collection`.

Unfortunately this code has a *magic number* which should be replaced by a constant with a meaningfull name:

```
private static final int TOP_POSITION = 0;
private final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();

public Card dealNextCard(){
    return this.deck.remove(TOP_POSITION);
}
```

Alternatively you could use a `LinkedList` object which provides the method `removeFirst()`:

```
private final LinkedList<Card> deck = new LinkedList<>();
public Card dealNextCard(){
    return this.deck.removeFirst();
}
```

This last version needs to be well thought since it violates the *program against interfaces* paradigm.